# HTML error when passing the prediction output using flask

Tags: python, html, machine-learning, flask

So as part of practicing flask and HTML, I have built a machine leanrning random forest classifier to classify whether the anime is good or not based on 6 features. I decided to pass this model to a python flask model for practice. it all worked good. However, the problem is I want to print "this anime is not good" if the output of the prediction = 0 and "this anime is good" if the output of the prediction = 1. I passed the value from flask to HTML and decided to use an if statement in the HTML file to check whether the passed element from prediction equals 1 or not and pass a message accordingly.

The probelm I encountered is if I passed values that I know would give a prediction = 0, it would not pass the "this anime is not good" message, but if I pass values that I know would give a prediction = 1, it gives the "this anime is good" message (I think this is just due to the if statement and not the HTML distinguishing what this value is).

anyways, how can I solve this problem keeping in mind that my random forest classifier works just fine and if I were to pass these values in vscode without flask and HTML I get the correct predictions so I know that the model is not the problem.

below is my flask code and HTML code respectively.

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template

app = Flask('Deploy') 
model = pickle.load(open('anime_review_classifier_final.pkl', 'rb'))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    int_features = [int(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    final_features = [np.array(int_features)]
    prediction = model.predict(final_features)
    output = int(prediction[0])  # Cast prediction to integer
    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text= output)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Anime Review Classifier</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Csstest.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Anime Review Classifier</h1>
    <form action="/predict" method="post">
        <!-- Add input fields for the anime-related features -->
        <label for="feature1">Rate the Story:</label>
        <input type="text" name="feature1" id="feature1" required><br>
        <label for="feature2">Rate the Animation:</label>
        <input type="text" name="feature2" id="feature2" required><br>
        <label for="feature3">Rate the OSTs:</label>
        <input type="text" name="feature3" id="feature3" required><br>
        <label for="feature4">Rate the Characters:</label>
        <input type="text" name="feature4" id="feature4" required><br>
        <label for="feature5">Rate the Enjoyment:</label>
        <input type="text" name="feature5" id="feature5" required><br>
        <label for="feature6">Overall rating:</label>
        <input type="text" name="feature6" id="feature6" required><br>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Predict" id="predict-button">
    </form>
    
{% if prediction_text %}
    {% if prediction_text == 0 %}
        <h2>The anime is not good</h2>
    {% else %}
        <h2>The anime is good</h2>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}


</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your time and help.

I tried to classify the prediction output using Flask before passing it to HTML and that didn't work, I tried having the value in the HTML's file if statement as a string in addition to inverting the conditions and passing the prediction as a whole and not the first index.